# Getting sum from a dataset column

Tags: smartface.io

I want to get sum from a dataset column to a label. I have been trying it for a while but could not make it. So, it would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link about datasets, you should check this. It will be helpful : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/dataset-2/

You can reach the values in dataset such as: 
myLabel.text = Data.myDataset.columnName;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I already can reach the values. I want to get sum of values in dataset column.

Comment: var total = 0;
function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e) {
    total = total + parseInt(Data.myDataset.column1);
    Data.myDataset.moveNext();
    alert(total);
}      Try the code above, each time I press the button, it adds the value in the dataset to the total, and with moveNext it moves to the next value in dataset. At the second press, adds the second value in the dataset, and so on.